# Unrecognized selector error when creating MTLTexture object

Tags: ios, macos, gpu, metal

I used the following code to create an `MTLTexture` object (for clarity, only part of the code is listed).

```
int tmpbuf[4096]
id<MTLDevice> device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice();
MTLTextureDescriptor* desc = [MTLTextureDescriptor    texture2DDescriptorWithPixelFormat: MTLPixelFormatA8Unorm  width: 64 height:64 mipmapped: NO];
id<MTLTexture> input_texture    = [device newTextureWithDescpriptor:desc];

//memory for the texture
MTLOrigin texture_origin = { 0, 0,  0};
MTLSize   texture_size   = {64, 64, 0};
MTLRegion texture_region = {texture_origin, texture_size}; 
[input_texture  replaceRegion: texture_region mipmaplevel: 0 withBytes: tmpbuf bytesPerRow: 64 ];
```

When running the code:

```
id<MTLTexture> input_texture    = [device newTextureWithDescpriptor:desc];
```

An error that `[MTLIGAccelDevice newTextureWithDescpriptor:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fd0a3012200 was reported.` This code was compiled and run on the OS X system. I have no idea why this error happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to first add a `;` at the end of the first line and then add a non-null value for the third `MTLSize` argument. This code snippet below compiles just fine on my OS X 10.11.6 machine.

```
    int tmpbuf[4096];
    id<MTLDevice> device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice();
    MTLTextureDescriptor* desc = [MTLTextureDescriptor texture2DDescriptorWithPixelFormat: MTLPixelFormatA8Unorm  width: 64 height:64 mipmapped: NO];
    id<MTLTexture> input_texture = [device newTextureWithDescriptor:desc];
    MTLOrigin texture_origin = { 0, 0,  0};
    MTLSize   texture_size   = {64, 64, 1};
    MTLRegion texture_region = {texture_origin, texture_size};
    [input_texture replaceRegion:texture_region mipmapLevel:0 withBytes:tmpbuf bytesPerRow:64];
```

Comment: Could it run successfully on your machine? @Marius

Comment: yes, did you make those 2 modifications followed by a Clean project? It should work on yours too now.

Comment: I have made the modifications, but it did not work. The same error was reported, when the code was run.

Comment: create a new empty project and use that snippet above to see that it works fine. after that, trying finding which other line in your code (that I didn't see) might be causing that error.

Comment: It worked in a new empty project. The error would be caused by other line of my code. Thanks @Marius

Comment: Note that using one of the region utility functions, such as `MTLRegionMake2D`, can make this code more concise.